# Is it possible to write real unit tests instead of mocking unit tests for Web API Controllers using Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to write unit tests for my new ASP.NET Web API. I'm using Ninject for Dependency Injection and would like to write the tests which help me test my API controllers/methods directly instead of using mocking feature. I'm having trouble connecting to database while running these unit tests. Is there any other way to write these tests which gets the actual data from database while testing the API.
Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have also written the test cases using ninject to connect with DB and get the data as per expectation and it was working absolutely fine. Hence, There is no rocket science behind this. To comment more on this I need bit more details to understand the exception which you are getting.

Comment: It is a lot easier in .net core, but even with full .net you basically just write code that starts your web app on a known port on localhost and make some HTTP requests to it...

Comment: **unit** test are tests without any real dependency (any depedency has to be faked/mocked). Once you use any real dependency you are on **integration** test. It is the same as you cannot paint a red line with blue ink => [the expert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg&vl=de) ;o)